# How to add rows in Excel based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

Folliwing eduroc.92's question. How can we add rows dynamically based on cell value? We have this piece of code for now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StartingRow As Long
    Dim StartingArrangement As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(1, 2)) Is Nothing Then
        With Me
            StartingRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            If StartingRow < 3 Then
                StartingRow = 2
            Else
                StartingArrangement = CLng(Trim(Replace(Replace(.Cells(StartingRow, 1), "Arrangement ", vbNullString), ":", vbNullString)))
            End If

            For i = 1 To .Cells(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(StartingRow, 1).Offset(i, 0).Value2 = "Arrangement " & StartingArrangement + i & ":"
            Next i
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

We have a couple of questions, sorry for being a jerk:

Is there a way to prevent overwriting existing data in the spreadsheet?, we would like that rows be added, yes, but that the existing data be moved downwards:

In this example, if the user wish to add five (5) arrangements it will surely overwrite existing data on the spreadsheet...

[Excel example #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCAk7.jpg)

Can we prevent rows from being add up every time the user inputs a new number instead to only show arrangements due to the new quantity input?

In this example, the user adds five arrangements, the rows were created successfully...

[Excel example #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbcKn.jpg)

But then, in the same spreadsheet, if the user adds 3 arrangements, it doesn't erase the old ones instead, it adds more and if there is any data below, it will overwrite it

We will surely appreciate all the help we can get, also, if there is something not quite understandable, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a title and some code doesn't make a compelling question.  What is the actual problem you're having?  Does your code produce an error, or if not then what?

Comment: I see no where in your code where you tried to add a row.

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded it the wrong way, just updated it!

Comment: Your code should never overwrite anything in ColA, because you're always getting your starting point by using End(xlUp) from the bottom of that column, then writing beginning one row down from there.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent overwrite existing data adding new rows you can insert rows with something like this:

```
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

You just have to set dynamically the row number.

I did not understand the issue related to example #2.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StartingRow As Long
    Dim StartingArrangement As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(1, 2)) Is Nothing Then
        With Me
            StartingRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            If StartingRow < 3 Then
                StartingRow = 2
            Else
                StartingArrangement = CLng(Trim(Replace(Replace(.Cells(StartingRow, 1), "Arrangement ", vbNullString), ":", vbNullString)))
            End If

            For i = 1 To .Cells(1, 2).Value2
                '**** insert a line and move down all the others *****
                .Cells(StartingRow, 1).Offset(i, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown

                .Cells(StartingRow, 1).Offset(i, 0).Value2 = "Arrangement " & StartingArrangement + i & ":"
            Next i
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The above will insert a row and move down everything below before writing the Arrangement line. Not sure if that is what you are after or not. Maybe comment your code so that we know what each line is supposed to do?